# Logging into and sending email automatically

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, cdo.message

I have an autoexec macro to send an email if a condition is met.

I would like this email to come from a specific email address no matter who opens the database.

I have the email account and password, but I'm not sure how to (or if it's even possible) to sign into an email account and send the email through VBA.

Solutions I've seen involve using `.SendUsingAccount`, however, that requires the user to be signed into the email account. Preferably, signing into the account would be done within the VBA so it doesn't matter if a user is logged into the account.

Answer (score 1):

Use CDO and send via SMTP to the server of the mail account:

[VBA – CDO Mail](https://www.devhut.net/2014/11/29/vba-cdo-mail/)